# How can I use the grep --color command to highlight brackets?

Tags: command-line, text-processing, grep

I want to highlight every `[` in any color so i can see the hidden message here:

```
[###[#[[[#[###[#[[[#[[[#[###[#[[[
[###[##[##[[##[#[####[##[[##[##[#
[######[##[#[#[#[[[##[##[#[#[##[#
[######[##[##[[#[####[##[##[[##[#
[[[###[[[#[###[#[###[[[#[###[#[[[
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to match `[` but, in `grep`, `[` is a regex active character.  The solution is to escape it with a backslash so that `grep` will treat it as a plain simple literal character:

```
grep --color=always '\[' fname
```

The output looks like:

[image]